# fast way to create a big bitmap from an array of bitmap?

Tags: c#, vb.net, bitmap, gdi+, unsafe

I have this code,

copy/paste in a new winform app and this will write a file on your desktop if you run it: `test123abcd.png`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SquareSize = 5
    Dim GridX = 2500
    Dim GridY = 2500
    Dim SquareCount = GridX * GridY - 1
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch

    Dim Rect(4) As Rectangle
    Rect(0) = New Rectangle(0, 3, 3, 1)
    Rect(1) = New Rectangle(3, 0, 1, 3)
    Rect(2) = New Rectangle(3, 3, 3, 1)
    Rect(3) = New Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 3)

    Dim fullsw = Stopwatch.StartNew
    Using board = New Bitmap(SquareSize * (GridX + 1), SquareSize * (GridY + 1), Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
        Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(board)
            Using _board = New Bitmap(SquareSize, SquareSize, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
                Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_board)
                    For i = 0 To SquareCount
                        g.Clear(If((i And 1) = 1, Color.Red, Color.Blue))
                        g.FillRectangles(Brushes.White, Rect)
                        sw.Start()
                        graph.DrawImageUnscaled(_board, ((i Mod GridX) * SquareSize), ((i \ GridY) * SquareSize))
                        sw.Stop()
                    Next
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        fullsw.Stop()
        board.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) & "\test123abcd.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Full SW: " & fullsw.ElapsedMilliseconds & Environment.NewLine &
                    "DrawImageUnscaled SW: " & sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub
```

about 40% to 45% of the time spent is on `DrawImageUnscaled`, about 23 seconds on my current computer while the whole thing take about 50 seconds

is there a way to speed up `DrawImageUnscaled`? (and maybe the whole thing?)

**EDIT** - question in vb.net, answer in c#

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? (inputs/outputs)

Comment: @varocarbas, I want to save the full bitmap that is split up into pieces

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any input image or any Color array. You are basically affecting the positions/sizes of pixels from blank bitmaps. That's why my question of inputs/outputs; for example in case of getting image1.png and image2.png as inputs and wanting to merge them together into imageEnd.png you wouldn't need to do all that. If you want to rescale the images, you wouldn't need to do all that either, etc. The best way to (appreciably) speed up this loop is taking a different approach which might be possible depending upon the exact conditions.

Comment: @varocarbas, input is unknown number of small `_board` which are `Bitmap` created in memory, which is done by the call to `refreshSquare`, output is `board` which is a huge `Bitmap` created in memory so it can be filled by all the `_board`

Comment: I am doing some tests and DrawImageUnscaled is clearly taking too long. Unfortunately I am not completely certain of what it does; I am using a simple copy pixel by pixel from one array to the other (what is much, much faster) but I cannot get the same result than with DrawImageUnscale. Actually speaking, it delivers a somehow weird behaviour (by using it as you are using it in your code): it does not copy all the pixels exactly (eventually located in different positions) but also includes further information (a blue background in my case)...

Comment: ... did I understand it properly and the only thing you want is copying the information of one bit map into other my applying some scale (e.g., converting the X,Y point 1,1 into 5,5)? In that case copying pixel by pixel is much (, much) faster and delivers the right output (at least, the one I would expect). Shall I go ahead and write an answer?

Comment: @varocarbas, I changed my code above with actual working code. Mostly, I have a list of tiles (bitmap), I just want to create the full bitmap from them

Comment: I have taken a look at your updated code and the problem is not easy: you don't rely on pixels, but on bunches of pixels (the rectangles you are creating), this complicates the situation. On top of that, DrawImageUnscaled is not the only high-time-waster, FillRectangles takes also quite a long time (and it cannot be avoided as far as the image hasn't been created yet). The proceeding is highly inneficient but the given constraints (bitmaps being created "on the go") do not help. DrawImageUnscaled, apparently, can be replaced by a mere copy/paste of pixels (a much faster process)...

Comment: ... the problem is that you don't know the current pixel being analysed (the current X/Y position) and thus would have to come up with something to calculate it (not extremely difficult, but neither too easy). It is not clear how much this change will improve the speed (as said, the FillRectangles part is also pretty time consuming) and, in any case, I think that it is beyond the kind of solution which I can deliver under the current conditions (more or less quick answers + some discussion). Do you want from me to write an answer? I will explain all this better and show pixel-copying approach.

Comment: @varocarbas, yes please write an answer, it might help figuring out another way for me to implement a new solution. tonight i think i will try to create a bytes arrays and create everything manually to see how it will perform.

Comment: I posted it. As said, I understand that more than enough for an answer here. Actually speaking it represents a full answer to your title; although just a starting point for your specific conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wow I like unsafe code when it is worthed, solved my problem with c# in the end

here is the code, which is about 70x faster to the code in my question

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace BmpFile
{
    public class BmpTest
    {
        private const int PixelSize = 4;

        public static long Test(int GridX, int GridY, int SquareSize, Rectangle[][] Rect)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(GridX * SquareSize, GridY * SquareSize, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                                          System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                          bmp.PixelFormat);

            int Stride = bmd.Stride;
            int Height = bmd.Height;
            int Width = bmd.Width;

            int RectFirst = Rect.GetUpperBound(0);
            int RectSecond;
            int Offset1, Offset2, Offset3;
            int i, j, k, l, w, h;
            int FullRow = SquareSize * Stride;
            int FullSquare = SquareSize * PixelSize;

            var sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            unsafe
            {
                byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;

                //draw all rectangles
                for (i = 0; i <= RectFirst; ++i)
                {

                    Offset1 = ((i / GridX) * FullRow) + ((i % GridX) * FullSquare) + 3;
                    RectSecond = Rect[i].GetUpperBound(0);

                    for (j = 0; j <= RectSecond; ++j)
                    {
                        Offset2 = Rect[i][j].X * PixelSize + Rect[i][j].Y * Stride;
                        w=Rect[i][j].Width;
                        h=Rect[i][j].Height;
                        for (k = 0; k <= w; ++k)
                        {
                            Offset3 = k * PixelSize;
                            for (l = 0; l <= h; ++l)
                            {
                                row[Offset1 + Offset2 + Offset3 + (l * Stride)] = 255;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //invert color
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
                {
                    Offset1 = (y * Stride) + 3;

                    for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                    {
                        if (row[Offset1 + x * PixelSize] == 255)
                        {
                            row[Offset1 + x * PixelSize] = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row[Offset1 + x * PixelSize] = 255;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

            bmp.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            bmp.Dispose();

            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By assuming that the generation part (`g.FillRectangles(Brushes.White, Rect)`, pretty time-consuming too) cannot be avoided, the best thing you can do is avoiding a second graph-generation process (also for `board`) and just copying the information from `_board`. Copying is much quicker than a new generation (as shown below), but you have the problem that the source information (`_board`) do not match the destination format (`board` by relying on `.SetPixel`) and thus you will have to create a function determining the current pixel (X/Y point) from the provided information (current rectangle).

Below you can see a simple code showing the time requirement differences between both approaches:

```
Dim SquareSize As Integer = 5
Dim _board As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromFile("in.png")
Dim board As Bitmap = New Bitmap(_board.Width * SquareSize, _board.Height * SquareSize)

For x As Integer = 0 To _board.Width - 1
    For y As Integer = 0 To _board.Height - 1
        board.SetPixel(x * SquareSize, y * SquareSize, _board.GetPixel(x, y))
    Next
Next

board.Save("out1.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)


board = New Bitmap(_board.Width, _board.Height)

Using board
    Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(board)
        Using _board
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_board)
                For x As Integer = 0 To _board.Width - 1
                    For y As Integer = 0 To _board.Height - 1
                        graph.DrawImageUnscaled(_board, x, y)
                    Next
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    board.Save("out2.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
End Using
```

Bear in mind that it is not a "properly-working code". Its whole point is showing how to copy pixels between bitmaps (by multiplying by a factor, just to get different outputs than inputs); and putting the `DrawImageUnscaled` method under equivalent conditions (although the output picture is, logically, different) to get a good feeling of the differences in time requirements between both methodologies.

As said via comment, this is all what I can do under the current conditions. I hope that will be enough to help you find the best solution.

Comment: I took your idea of doing each individual pixel and I created a solution, look at my answer for the code. Thanks! +1

Comment: @Fredou i am happy that you were able to solve your problem. +1 for you. I haven't tested your code but I guess that it works fine. One small but: your code is in C# and the question tagged as VB.NET.

Comment: I updated the tag with a small edit explaining why both, vb.net and c#, are used.

Comment: @Fredou OK, thanks for letting me know. You should go ahead and award your answer as the right one; usually, I am not too fan of people asking and answering themselves, but in this case it is clearly the right answer (despite saying that, I haven't tested your code yet :)).

Comment: The code(c#) does reproduce the same output that i was doing previously(vb.net) and is 70x faster (sometime more). In my question i was saying that it was taking 50 seconds, now the same thing take less than 0.7 seconds. That is a wow factor for me that i wasn't expecting.

Comment: @Fredou yes, I got that. As shown in my simplistic test, the time-requirement difference between creating a bitmap and just copying pixels is huge (and you were creating two!!!). I guess that you have this clear, but just in case someone reads this and doesn't have the ideas too clear: nothing to do with VB.NET or C#; your code converted to VB.NET will output equivalent performance. Anyway... you are the one who built the code and thus you really deserve the award.

Comment: If you are curious to what this code does look at this playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlhq3CF5UWUXllfdLN7RrHjFxUHS10g7C it allow me to record maze creation and generate screen in a way faster. My program has scrollbar, so the screen need to refresh often(CPU intensive). The 30 seconds video are 30x50, which mean 1500 bitmaps, and the 7 minutes 30 seconds are 150x150, which mean 22500 bitmaps. So this 70x speed increase does have an impact!

Comment: @Fredou you have a big passion for mazes, don't you? :) Very nice, the last videos look much better and the difference in speed with respect to the old ones is evident.

Comment: I like to do small thing like that to pastime or for challenge or learning / testing new thing :-)