# Way to make this unsafe struct with fixed array dynamic? (or an alternative?)

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

I'm currently having this;

```
    private const int PixelSizeBGR = 3;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private unsafe struct BGR5
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        private fixed byte bgr[PixelSizeBGR * 5];

        public BGR5(byte b, byte g, byte r)
        {
            fixed (byte* v = bgr) 
            {
                int num = 0;
                do
                {
                    v[num++] = b; v[num++] = g; v[num++] = r;
                } while (num < (PixelSizeBGR * 5));
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private unsafe struct BGR3
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        private fixed byte bgr[PixelSizeBGR * 3];

        public BGR3(byte b, byte g, byte r)
        {
            fixed (byte* v = bgr)
            {
                int num = 0;
                do
                {
                    v[num++] = b; v[num++] = g; v[num++] = r;
                } while (num < (PixelSizeBGR * 3));
            }
        }
    }
```

you can see the pattern I think.

Is there a way to make it dynamic since i might find out that i need more of these?

or is there any alternative?

practical example;

BEFORE, 24000 pixel by 24000 pixel bitmap, 2151 milliseconds

```
            byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;

            /*** stuff ***/

            Offset1 = ((CurrentPos / GridX) * FullRow) + ((CurrentPos % GridX) * FullSquare);
            for (k = PixelSize; k <= w; k += PixelSize)
            {
                Offset1 += PixelSize;
                for (l = Stride; l <= h; l += Stride)
                {
                    row[l + Offset1] = 0; //b
                    row[l + Offset1 + 1] = 255; //g
                    row[l + Offset1 + 2] = 255; //r
                }
            }
            /*** more stuff ***/
```

AFTER, 24000 pixel by 24000 pixel bitmap, 944 milliseconds

```
            byte* row = (byte*)bmd.Scan0;

            /*** stuff ***/

            np5.Set(0, 255, 255);
            Offset1 = ((CurrentPos / GridX) * FullRow) + ((CurrentPos % GridX) * FullSquare) + PixelSizeBGR;
            h = Stride;
            do
            {
                *((BGR5*)(row + h + Offset1)) = np5;
                h += Stride;
            } while (h < FullRow);

            /*** more stuff ***/
```

AFTER is more than 50% faster

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind all the unsafe / fixed / pointer code? There is nothing inside your structs that seem to require it, but I'm guessing you need it for how these are being used.

Comment: @nicholas, I'm creating bitmap dynamically and instead of having a loop to set 3 or 5 pixel in a row the same color, I'm using these struct. I did some benchmark and it is worthed, I would like to know if this could be made a little more generic, I'm not really familiar with unsafe/pointer so feel free to suggest alternative :-)

Comment: i still am not sure why you might not just use a regular byte array and then parse it out to file with a number of built-in methods that C# includes. if someone else doesn't beat me to it, i will post an answer later tonight. also, what about using some of the built-in image and bitmap libraries already supplied by .NET?

Comment: @nicholas, look at one of my previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083318 , building it manually with pointer speeded up by 70x the creation of the bitmap, these struct, above, remove the need of this loop `for (k = 0; k <= w; ++k)` which save about 15% to 20% of processing time. in the end the struct behave like loop unrolling.

Comment: You just get no mileage out of declarations like these.  Write a method, not a struct.  Pass the byte* and the size, write a for() loop.

Comment: @HansPassant, I had a for loop before and by doing these struct I was able to remove the for loop and gain about 20 to 30% in processing speed, I'm using the struct as a unrolling way. I'm going to update my question with some actual code

Comment: @Fredou, I suspect that your boost in speed may be related to the reduced amount of arithmetic going on such as the additions in your array indexers. i would be willing to bet you you made a separate R, G, and B loop with proper for initialization, you would see similar gains. I will do a test later this morning on it.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the question of whether this **should** be done or if there are better ways of doing this, I will attempt to answer the OP's desire to create runtime sizeable structures that can be used for variable length memory block copies. In short, performing high performance byte-level manipulations of data is more suited for C++ than C#, but it appears it is still technically possible.

To accomplish this, we can use marshalling to dynamically create unmanaged memory of variable size to hold our temporary `BGRn` data and then use P/Invoke to perform the block memory copy.

```
public unsafe class BGRn
{
    IntPtr bgrPtr;
    int totalSize;
    const int pixelSizeBGR = 3;

    public BGRn(byte b, byte g, byte r, int size)
    {
        totalSize = pixelSizeBGR * size;
        bgrPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(totalSize);

        byte* v = (byte*)bgrPtr;

        int num = 0;

        do
        {
            v[num++] = b;
            v[num++] = g;
            v[num++] = r;
        } while (num < (totalSize));
    } 

    public void CopyTo(IntPtr buffer)
    {
        CopyMemory(buffer, bgrPtr, (uint) totalSize);
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

}
```

You can then leave the other code as is except replace:

```
BGR5 np5 = new BGR5(0, 255, 255);
// ...
*((BGR5*)(row + h + Offset1)) = np5;
```

with:

```
BGRn np5 = new BGRn(0, 255, 255, 5);
// ...
np5.CopyTo((IntPtr)(row + h + Offset1));
```

Of course, I have left out the `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` that should go along with this class, but that is up to the user to decide how and when to free the memory (probably by implementing `IDisposable` and a `using` statement).

*I have not actually tested how this code performs or if it even works, but it does compile.*

Comment: I'm going to do some benchmark later today, +1 for now, thanks :-)

Comment: sadly this code seem to be 3x slower than using a struct :-( btw you should fix the code provided, you switched the copyTo dest/src, should be CopyMemory(buffer, bgrPtr, (uint) totalSize); and the totasize should be totalSize = pixelSizeBGR * size;

Answer (score 0):

Using an absract base class can ease the work with bitmaps of any width, albeit you will still need to write a separate class for each bitmap width. You don't need structs- you can write direct to bitmap's memory.

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace TestProject2
{
public abstract class BGRBase
{
    //init to your bitmap's BitmapData, obtained by calling Bitmap.LockBits
    protected readonly BitmapData data;

    public abstract void SetRow(int rowIndex, byte b, byte g, byte r);
}

public class BGR3 : BGRBase
{
    //use constructor to ensure that the bitmap's width is compatible

    public unsafe override void SetRow(int rowIndex, byte b, byte g, byte r)
    {
        byte* row = (byte*)data.Scan0 + rowIndex * data.Stride;
        row[0] = row[3] = row[6] = b;
        //etc
    }
}

public class BGR5 : BGRBase
{
    public override unsafe void SetRow(int rowIndex, byte b, byte g, byte r)
    {
        //code as adove
    }
}
}
```

Or, use a delegate to encapsulate an appropriate method and call it in the loop

```
public static void Set5(byte* p, byte b, byte g, byte r)

public static void Set3(byte* p, byte b, byte g, byte r)

//usage
public void Draw(Rectangle rect, byte b, byte g, byte r)
{
    Action<byte*, byte, byte, byte> setRow = null;
    switch(rect.Width)
    {
        case 3: setRow = Set3; break;
        case 5: setRow = Set5; break;
        //etc
    }
    byte* p=(byte*)bmd.Scan0 + bmd.Stride * rect.Y + 3 * rect.X;
    while(p < endAddress)
    {
        setRow(p, b, g, r);
        p+=bmd.Stride;  
    }
}
```